# How to read string value from file(notepad.txt) to hex values in array via CAPL

Tags: capl

The notepad contains alphanumerical characters with spaces.
Example:

Name
00 01 20 F2 4F

How to read these values from this notepad.txt file to hex in array?

Comment: So with which part are your problems? Opening a file? Reading from the file? Converting the string? Please show what you have achieved so far and where exactly your problems are.

Comment: i can able to fetch the values from notepad by using FilegetString function, actually i need a values in hex format, so tried to use atol function, which return in decimal. I see there is no string to hex conversion in CAPL, so yes, now it resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the atol function, you have essentially converted the sting to a number format.
You can either display (while printing in write window) that value in decimal or hexadecimal.